# Search the object from the array in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to search the object from the ArrayList

For example, in the below code the object of Product class is going to stored in the ArrayList. Now, I want to find the Product using its product name (by contain method).

```
import java.util.*;

class Product {
    String name;
    int price;
    int id;
    Product(int i, String name, int price) {
        this.id=i;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> al = new ArrayList<Product>();
        al.add(new Product(1, "Samsung", 10000));
        al.add(new Product(2, "Apple", 20000));
        al.add(new Product(3, "Nokia", 30000));
        al.add(new Product(4, "Sony", 40000));
        al.add(new Product(5, "LG", 50000));
        for (Product p : al) {
            System.out.println(p.id + " " + p.name + " " + p.price);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the product to search:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        if (al.contains(name)) {
            System.out.println("Product found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Product not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as per your program `name` is a String variable.  Searching a string in your ArrayList wont find the product object.  `al` is an ArrayList of Products. Create a Product object and search in the ArrayList. Also, does the Product class has hashCode and equals methods override?

Comment: But if I Create the Product Object to search then I have to specify the id and price of it to search.

Comment: Yes, if you are searching for a product then it has to be full `Product` object. If not you you can use latest features of streams to filter out Product objects that have some criterion.

```List<Product> productsWithName= products
  .stream()
  .filter(p-> p.getName().equals("compareing Name"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());```

Comment: The simple solution is to use a `for` loop to iterate the list, testing each element until you find a match.  Streams are a more elegant solution, but they requires you to understand streams, lambdas and so on ... which you probably haven't learned yet.  (Based on the kind of code you showed us.)  And if you just copy someone else's stream solution, your teacher may ask you to explain how it works, where you got it from, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

The contains() method checks whether a string contains a sequence of characters.

You cannot search in product object directly by contains() method, so first you must be get name variable of product object and then search what you want:

```
    for (Product p : al) {
        System.out.println(p.id + " " + p.name + " " + p.price);
        if (p.name.equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("Product found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Product not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "The contains() method checks whether a string contains a sequence of characters." This is a different `contains()` method than the one the OP is using. They are calling `ArrayList.contains()`, not `String.contains()`.

Comment: And you probably want `p.name.equals(name)` instead of `p.name.contains()`.

Comment: Thank you for focused on my answer. I have wanted write name in method input but didnt it cause i have thought i dont write any thing that anyone write anything that want to search on method. I have knew contains() get string parameter in method signature.

Comment: Now i have changed `p.name.contains()` to `p.name.equals(name)`

Answer (score 1):

`contains`Returns true if this list contains the specified element. While element in the list is `Product` and `name` is `String`, it always returns false in your case.

Try to implement your logic with a for loop on the whole list and check whether there is a product whose name is the desired name.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

kuriboh's explanation about why the `contains` method does not work in your sample is clear and I believe there is nothing to add to explain why your code is not working as you expected.

That being said, I know people recommended to loop through all the elementes in your list to compare by name and find the entry in the list that matches your criteria search.  Another way to perform the product search by name is using lambda expressions.

```
//Search using lambda expression, comparing product name
Optional<Product> productFound = al.stream().filter(prod -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(prod.name)).findFirst();
if (productFound.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("Product found");
    System.out.println(productFound.get());
} else {
    System.out.println("Product not found");
}
```

Running example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Products {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> al = new ArrayList<Product>();
        al.add(new Product(1, "Samsung", 10000));
        al.add(new Product(2, "Apple", 20000));
        al.add(new Product(3, "Nokia", 30000));
        al.add(new Product(4, "Sony", 40000));
        al.add(new Product(5, "LG", 50000));
        for (Product p : al) {
            System.out.println(p.id + " " + p.name + " " + p.price);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the product to search:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        //Search using lambda expression, comparing product name
        Optional<Product> productFound = al.stream().filter(prod -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(prod.name)).findFirst();
        if (productFound.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Product found");
            System.out.println(productFound.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Product not found");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}

class Product {
    String name;
    int price;
    int id;
    Product(int i, String name, int price) {
        this.id = i;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Product [name=%s, price=%s, id=%s]", name, price, id);
    }

}
```

Console output

```
1 Samsung 10000
2 Apple 20000
3 Nokia 30000
4 Sony 40000
5 LG 50000
Enter the name of the product to search:
Apple
Product found
Product [name=Apple, price=20000, id=2]
```

I hope this is helpful.

Happy Coding!

Karl